# How can I reference a previous selection from a UI list and change a second row accordingly?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of Hazard labels with a column of shorthand and another of the longhand version.

In my user interface I have a dropdown menu to select the shorthand hazard label from that list and am wondering if I can reference this decision in realtime to automatically update the longhand field without additional selection?

Comment: Without additional information about how your system works there is no way we can assist.

Comment: So there's no general format for value(instance of x cell)?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about... you have provided no context, no code...